# Add NA randomly to dataset in R without changing factor to integer

Tags: r, dataframe, na, data-wrangling

If I create a mock dataset, I'd like to add NA to my data to make it more realistic.

However, I cannot add NA while keep the type of a variable as a factor. Adding NAs change a factor variable to integer.  For example,

```
mockdf <- data.frame(
  age_f = c("young", "young", "old", "young", "old", "old"),
  awareness_rating = c("somewhat", "a lot", "not at all", "a lot", "a lot", "not at all"),
  risk_rating = c("somewhat", "not at all", "a little", "a little", "a lot", "not at all"),
  like_rating = c("somewhat", "not at all", "not at all", "a lot", "a lot", "not at all")
)
mockdf <- mockdf %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.factor))

#  age_f awareness_rating risk_rating like_rating
#1 young         somewhat    somewhat    somewhat
#2 young            a lot  not at all  not at all
#3   old       not at all    a little  not at all
#4 young            a lot    a little       a lot
#5   old            a lot       a lot       a lot
#6   old       not at all  not at all  not at all
```

I want to keep these columns as factors and throw in some NA for 2nd and 4th columns (5% of the data).

I look up solutions and found that this code work

```
mockdf<- mockdf %>% mutate(
  across(.cols= (c(2,4)),
         .fns = ~ifelse(rbinom(n(), 1, 0.04), NA, .x))
```

but it changes them into numbers like below:

```
#age_f awareness_rating risk_rating like_rating
#1 young                3    somewhat           3
#2 young                4  not at all           1
#3   old                1    a little           1
#4 young                4    a little          NA
#5   old                4       a lot           4
#6   old                1  not at all           1
```

I know if I flip the order of my codes and run my mutate(across()) code at the end, it solves the problem. However, I think there is got to be a way to add NA without messing up with the type of variables and wonder if anyone knows the answer.

Comment: It's documented that `ifelse()` is not suitable for non-atomic data types because it strips attributes.  You can use `dplyr::if_else()` but change your test so it resolves to a logical vector, i.e. `~ if_else(rbinom(n(), 1, 0.04) == 1L, NA, .x)`.